# Update with subquery not working mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join, limit, where-clause

This is my select query which works fine :

```
   SELECT PRICE.PRICEDATETO AS PDF
    ,ATTR.PRICEDATEFROM AS ADF
    ,ATTR.PRICEDATETO AS ADT 
    FROM RT_DATA_CORE DCORE 
       INNER JOIN RT_DATA_PRICE PRICE ON DCORE.ID=PRICE.ID 
       INNER JOIN RT_PRODUCT_CORE PCORE ON PCORE.ID=PRICE.PRODUCTID 
       INNER JOIN RT_DATA_PRICEATTRIBUTES ATTR ON        
              CONCAT(ATTR.PRODUCTID,'_V')=PCORE.SKU 
          AND PRICE.ID='PRICE-26095657' 
          AND ATTR.PRICEDATETO>NOW() 
   ORDER BY ATTR.PRICEDATETO ASC LIMIT 1;
```

I need to update it to ADF=PDF

I am trying this which gives me an error:

> mysql> UPDATE RT_DATA_PRICE PRICE INNER JOIN (SELECT PA.PRICEDATETO AS DATER,PCORE.ID AS PID FROM RT_DATA_PRICEATTRIBUTES PA,RT_PRODUCT_CORE PCORE WHERE PA.PRICEDATETO > NOW() AND PCORE.SKU = CONCAT(PA.PRODUCTID,'_V') ORDER BY PA.PRICEDATETO ASC LIMIT 1)AOP ON AOP.PID=PRICE.PRODUCTID AND PRICE.ID='PRICE-26095657' SET AOP.DATER=PRICE.PRICEDATETO;
>   ERROR 1288 (HY000): The target table AOP of the UPDATE is not updatable

Comment: Ok, can you show us your update not as error?

Answer (score 0):

The table `RT_DATA_CORE` is not being used so I've removed it, try this

```
UPDATE RT_DATA_PRICE PRICE, RT_PRODUCT_CORE PCORE, RT_DATA_PRICEATTRIBUTES ATTR
SET ATTR.PRICEDATEFROM = PRICE.PRICEDATETO 
WHERE
    PCORE.ID=PRICE.PRODUCTID 
    CONCAT(ATTR.PRODUCTID,'_V')=PCORE.SKU 
    AND PRICE.ID='PRICE-26095657' 
    AND ATTR.PRICEDATETO>NOW();
```